# Comma after "and that"

Tags: commas

On the website http://web.ku.edu/~edit/that.html, there is the sentence

> "The senator said that he might run again and that, if he did, Myra Henry would be his campaign manager."

I don't think there should be a comma after the word "that":

> The senator said that he might run again and that if he did, Myra Henry would be his campaign manager.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I'd not class either as unacceptable.

Comment: They're both fine; it's just a matter of style.

Comment: But I feel, due to inserting "if he did", the commas are justified.

Answer (score 1):

I read it as a parenthetical element.  'if he did' could be removed from the sentence without changing the meaning.  Some examples should make this clear (taken from http://grammartips.homestead.com/interrupters.html):

> Take, *for example*, the way Linda responded to being accused of
>   bias.
>
> That explanation, *as I have already said*, doesn't really hold water.
>
> You should, *nevertheless*, continue your efforts despite this recent 
>   disappointment.
>
> He cannot, *however*, hope to defeat a popular incumbent.

The italicised parts are parenthetical elements.  They could be removed from the sentence and it would still read correctly.